# In JSF2 how to avoid #{class.value} being treated as value retrieval from Mangaged Bean?

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, javabeans

```
I have a bean class as "UserBean" and it has an bean value as "name"
/**** UserBean bean class****/
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UserBean {
    private String name;  

    public UserBean() {
    }

   //getter and setter for name
}

now in XHTML file (using JSF2 tags) when i am writing this 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>UseBean as Plain Text</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
<h1> hello its me #UserBean.name </h:form></h:body></html>
```

in browser it retrieves the value of name field but i dont want this to happen.
    what i want is to just have a plain text in the browser page i.e "hello its me #UserBean.name"

how to do this??

Comment: Try either `\#` or just use the entity, `&#35;`

Comment: @McDowell it may be but in that discussion I didnt found my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it using "\" and `<outputtext>` tag

i did this - `<h:outputText value="hello - \#\{userBean.name}" escape="false" />`